# set limit in selection for sumo dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, sumoselect.js

I have used this jquery plugin [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) for drop-down select with check-box

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="SlectBox" name="cat_ids[]">
    <option value="op1">Options1</option>
    <option value="op2">Options2</option>
    <option value="op3">Options3</option>
    <option value="op4">Options4</option>
    <option value="op5">Options5</option>  
</select>
```

This drop-down working fine with check-bow selections. 
But I want to put some limitation for different users with this selection.

I have tried below jquery code but it not working proper

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var last_valid_selection = null;
  $('.SlectBox').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
      alert('You can only choose 2!');
      $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
    } else {
      last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
    }
  });  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sumo methods `unSelectAll` and `selectItem` and the `triggerChangeCombined` option on the plugin init.

Ref: http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

In the change event if the limit is raised you can deselect all and set the last valid selection by the index of each element.

Code:

```
$('#island').SumoSelect({ triggerChangeCombined: true, placeholder: "TestPlaceholder" });

var last_valid_selection = null;
$('#island').change(function (event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
        alert('You can only choose 2!');
        var $this = $(this);
        $this[0].sumo.unSelectAll();
        $.each(last_valid_selection, function (i, e) {
            $this[0].sumo.selectItem($this.find('option[value="' + e + '"]').index());
        });
    } else {
        last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/80xLm01g/

Comment: It working but when call "$this[0].sumo.unSelectAll();"  also log error " Cannot read property 'length' of null" for me. Cant find where yet. I think it in sumo.js

Answer (score 0):

There is better sample.

Dont forgot triggerChangeCombined: true

```
    var last_selection = null;
    var load_selection = false;
    $('#SeasonIdList').change(function (event) {
        if (load_selection == true) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($(this).val() != null && $(this).val().length > 3) {
            load_selection = true;
            var $this = $(this);

            $this[0].sumo.unSelectAll();

            $.each(last_selection, function (i, e) {
                $this[0].sumo.selectItem($this.find('option[value="' + e + '"]').index());
            });

            load_selection = false;
        } else {
            last_selection = $(this).val();
        }
    });
```